# isalpha(<mychar>) == true evaluates to false?

Tags: c++

string temp  is equal to "ZERO:\t.WORD\t1" from my debugger. (the first line of my file)

```
string temp = RemoveWhiteSpace(data);
int i = 0;
if ( temp.length() > 0 && isalpha(temp[0]) )
    cout << "without true worked" << endl;
if ( temp.length() > 0 && isalpha(temp[0]) == true )
    cout << "with true worked" << endl;
```

This is my code to check if first character of temp is a a-z,A-Z. The first if statement will evaluate to true and the 2nd to false. WHY?!?!?! I have tried this even without the "temp.length() > 0 &&" and it still evaluates false. It just hates the "== true". The only thing I can think of is that isalpha() returns != 0 and true == 1. Then, you could get isalpha() == 2 != 1. But, I have no idea if C++ is that ... weird.

BTW, I dont need to know that the "== true" is logically pointless. I know.

output was

```
without true worked
```

Compiled with CodeBlock using GNU GCC on Ubuntu 9.10 (if this matters any)

Comment: Have you tried `cout << isalpha(temp[0]) << endl;` ?

Comment: "I have no idea if C++ is that ... weird". Consulting a reference manual would give you an idea. cplusplus.com says, "A value different from zero (i.e., `true`) if indeed *c* is an alphabetic letter". Which is why you shouldn't use cplusplus.com: `true` in C++ doesn't mean the same thing as "true" in the description in the C standard that they copied from. opengroup.org says, "The isalpha() function shall return non-zero if c is an alphabetic character", which is rather better.

Comment: Also, beware confusion between this isalpha function from `<cctype>` or `<ctype.h>`, and the function template `std::isalpha` in `<locale>`. The latter returns `bool`, so if you were calling that then your code would work.

Comment: Oh, and another thing, `isalpha(temp[0])` is wrong. You should write `isalpha((unsigned char)(temp[0]))`, or a static_cast if you insist. For reasons unclear to me, `isalpha` takes an `int` parameter which must be non-negative (or EOF), whereas `char` might be a signed type on your compiler (I believe it is if you're on Ubuntu on x86). Doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but there you go. I guess it was considered easier for callers to cast when reading from a string, than to check for EOF when reading from a stream.

Comment: Other questions that addressed this from a style standpoint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535397/boolean-code-clarity-which-style-to-use/1535562#1535562 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356217/should-i-use-isgood-or-isgood-false/356709#356709  My take is that comparing against `true`/`false` is bad style because it can lead to pitfalls like what you've run into.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The is* functions are only guaranteed to return a non-zero value if true, NOT necessarily a 1. A typical implementation is table based, with one entry in the table for each character value, and a set of bits defining which bit means what. The is* function will just AND the right bitmask with the table value, and return that, which will only be the value 1 for whichever type happens to have been given bit position 0.

E.g.:

```
#define __digit 1
#define __lower 2
#define __upper 4
extern int __type_table[];

int isdigit(int c) { 
    return __type_table[c+1] & __digit;
}

int isalpha(int c) { 
    return __type_table[c+1] & (__lower | __upper);
}

int islower(int c) { 
    return __type_table[c+1] & __lower;
}

int isupper(int c) { 
    return __type_table[c+1] & __upper;
}
```

Where `__type_table` is defined as something like `int __type_table[UINT_MAX+1];` and would be initialized so (for example) `__type_table['0'+1] == __digit` and `__type_table['A'+1] == __upper`.

In case you care, the '+1' part is to leave a spot at the beginning of the table for `EOF` (which is typically defined as -1).

Comment: @Buttink:now that you mention it, that does seem odd... :-)

Comment: @Buttink: liking C# is what got you into this mess - if it wasn't for C# you'd be happy just to use an integer in a conditional, which works, instead of comparing it to a single "truth" value, which doesn't because the C functions weren't designed for you to do that. It's fine to prefer C#, but it's not fine to pretend you're writing C# when you're really writing C++ ;-)

Comment: @steve No instead a bunch of lazy f**ks decided to make a logically bool function return an int. This wouldnt even happen if C didnt allow a bool to be implicitly converted to int. In assembler, you at least assume there is no type. C is a high level lanuages.

Comment: @Buttink:C didn't have a Boolean type when these were invented either. The design wasn't about laziness either, but about efficiency. Keep in mind that C was originally intended to take the place of hand-written assembly language, and they were serious about making it as close to the same efficiency as possible. Converting every non-zero value to a 1 didn't fit with that at all. The preface to *The C Programming Language* (1st Edition) specifically states that "C is not a very high level language..."

Comment: Not all that bad though. It's only required to care about ranges `0 .. UCHAR_MAX` or `EOF` :)

Answer (score 2):

`isalpha` doesn't return `true`, it returns non-zero. This is quite common for API designed for C.

Note that in the expression `isalpha(ch) == true`, the subexpression `true` is promoted to type `int` with value 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the documentation suggests that it returns either zero or non-zero, not necessarily just false or true.  So you'd better check (isalpha(temp[0]) != 0).

Comment: @mmyers: Or `isalpha(temp[0])`!

Comment: @UncleBens: *Hush, you'll kill my air of superiority.*

Answer (score 0):

Do not  `isalpha(ch) == true`, but `!!isalpha(ch) == true`

Comment: If you're going to compare a Boolean value to true (thus producing another Boolean value) are you sure that once is enough?  Maybe it should really be `(!!isalpha(ch)==true)==true`, or perhaps even `(((((!!isalpha(ch)==true)==true)==true)==true)==true`? Hey look, I've invented Lisp! :-)

Comment: Any expression with double ! signs needs to die. It's not ideomatic, it's ugly, and it's almost certainly not what you wanted to do anyway. -1.

Comment: @Jerry: I think the true connoisseur of boolean expressions starts with `(!!isalpha(ch)==(!!true==!!true))`, and takes it from there as the mood strikes.