# Why does isdigit() return 2048 if true?

Tags: c++, c, ctype

Can anybody explain why does `isdigit` return `2048` if true? I am new to `ctype.h` library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
  char c = '9';
  printf ("%d", isdigit(c));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because "C" doesn't have a "bool" type, but it has the concept of a boolean, such that "0" is "false" and everything else is "true", and 2048 != 0 so it is true.

Comment: C does have a `bool` type. More precisely, it has a built-in boolean type named `_Bool`, and a macro definition `#define bool _Bool` in the standard header `<stdbool.h>`. But that was added by the 1999 ISO C standard, and `isdigit()` predates it.

Comment: BTW: On other systems one may get a non-zero value other than 2048.

Comment: Just as an aside. If you really want true/false to be 1 or 0 just use the `!!` work-around: `printf("%d", !!isdigit(c));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [isalpha(<mychar>) == true evaluates to false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519627/isalphamychar-true-evaluates-to-false)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because it's allowed to.  The C99 standard says only this about `isdigit`, `isalpha`, etc:

> The functions in this subclause **return nonzero (true)** if and only if the value of the
>   argument `c` conforms to that in the description of the function.

As to why that's happening in practice, I'm not sure.  At a guess, it's using a lookup table shared with all the `is*` functions, and masking out all but a particular bit position.  e.g.:

```
static const int table[256] = { ... };

// ... etc ...
int isalpha(char c) { return table[c] & 1024; }
int isdigit(char c) { return table[c] & 2048; }
// ... etc ...
```

Comment: It is probably returning a bit field. 2048 has only one bit set. OP could check if other `is` functions also return a single bit set.

Comment: I don't know if this is the real implementation of `isdigit` but it seems like it could: http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/lib/ctype.c.html

Comment: @Coodey: **the** real implementation of `isdigit` does not exist. There are many implementations, none of which is the "most real".

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no standard document to define how to represented bool by specified number, and for C language, non-zero is true and zero is false. so it depends on actual implementation .

Comment: Does that add anything that's not already in the other answer?