# ReSharper telling me Boolean.TryParse() inside IF statement redundant?

Tags: c#, resharper

I would like some clarification on the following IF statement. I know this sort of statement can be written in many different ways... that's not what i'm asking. I am really curious why ReSharper 7 is telling me that comparing `canceled == true` is redundant.

```
bool canceled;
if (Boolean.TryParse(Request.QueryString["cancel"], out canceled) && 
    canceled == true)
{
    // Transaction canceled...
}
```

It's my understanding that `Boolean.TryParse()` will return true/false based on the success of the conversion, not the actual **result** of the out parameter. Why then would comparing `canceled == true` be redundant? It very well could be false at that point, right?

Comment: It's the use of `== true` that's redundant. You don't need to compare a bool to a bool to have it as a condition. =)

Comment: Yes, I see that now... man I feel stupid.

Comment: Happens to all of us. Well. Maybe not Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use

```
if (Boolean.TryParse(Request.QueryString["cancel"], out canceled) && canceled)
{
    // Transaction canceled...
}
```

As `canceled` is not nullable, you don't need to explicitly compare with the `true` boolean, as `(canceled == true) == canceled`.

Comment: Ah, thanks... DOH! I just realized ReSharper is not telling me that the entire `canceled == true` condition is redundant... only the `== true`.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977365/which-is-clearer-form-ifvalue-or-ifflag-value/2977394#2977394