# isalpha() function returns false for character in string

Tags: c++, string, debugging

I am trying to count the number of letters in a string by checking for every character in the string `foo`by using the pre-defined function `isalpha()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string foo = "aaaaaaa1";

    int count=0;

    for (int i=0;i<foo.length();i++)
    {
        if ( isalpha(foo[i]) == true)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout<<count;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Expected output :

> 7

Current output :

> 0

The error is that `function isalpha is not returning true for alphabetic` ,

Can someone explain to me why and how to solve the problem to check if a given character is a alphabetic

Comment: Comparing with `true` is an antipattern (at least in C and C++). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356217/should-i-use-isgood-or-isgood-false/356709#356709

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The return type of `isalpha` is `int`, not `bool` (it comes from C). It returns 0 when the check fails, and a nonzero value when it succeeds. Note that it does not have to return 1 in such case.

Comparing an `int` to `true` promotes the `true` to the integer 1. Then the comparison fails for integers other than 1.

You should never check logic values by comparing with `true` or `false` - rely on the value or implicit conversion instead:

```
if ( isalpha(foo[i]) )
{
  count++;
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/ZMSELS)

Answer (score 9):

`isalpha()` returns an `int`. You should check if it returns a value different from `0`.

Comment: No need to explicitly compare if it returns something other than zero. Just check it the return in "truthy".